# Rewrite Rule Outputs PHP Source Code Instead of Running Script

Tags: nginx

I have a PHP script that takes two variables and creates a dynamic image. If I access the script directly in the browser it works perfectly. However, I'm trying to use a rewrite rule to make the url nicer looking. Instead of the script executing, the browser downloads the .php source code. What am I doing wrong?

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /folder/subfolder;
    index index.html;
    server_name domain.com;
    location / {
        autoindex on;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html /index.php?$args;
        rewrite ^/images/(\d+)/(\d+)\.png /_images.php?x=$1&y=$2 last;
        }

    location ~ ^(.+\.php)(.*)$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please share an example request? Just want to check the regex. Something like `http://example.com/images/some/example.png` ?

Comment: `http://example.com/_images.php?x=123&y=4567` works but `http://example.com/images/123/4567.png` shows the _images.php source code.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. Your Rewrite rule is correct. In case NGINX severs the PHP-code as octet-stream output there is something wrong in your php location block. Have you tried this tutorial? https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/

Comment: ```location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }``` Thats mine PHP configuration on my servers.

Comment: Thank you very much! Changing `^(.+\.php)(.*)$` to `\.php$` allowed it to work correctly in both instances.